# Es correcto usar los archivos de traducción de laravel para almacenar datos con reglas de negocio?

Tags: laravel, arquitectura, traducción

Tengo una duda sobre como realizar lo siguiente.
Tengo una data que va a ser estática, con lo cual nunca va a cambiar. Así que he decidido poner esta data en arrays (como si fuesen configs).
Al usar internacionalización mi idea era la de usar los archivos de traducción (es, en, etc) pero claro esta data contiene reglas de negocio, me explico:

La aplicación consiste en generar asentamientos para juegos de rol de mesa.
Hay diferentes tipos de asentamientos: Puestos comerciales, pueblos, villas, ciudades, etc.
Cada uno de estos asentamientos tiene unos atributos asociados, por ejemplo puestos comerciales:
Origen, Especialidad, Antigüedad, Estado, etc.
Los puestos comerciales si que tienen un modelo con una tabla (id, user_id, name, description, origin, speciality, etc)
Pero a la hora de generarlos es cuando se consultan estas tablas/arrays estáticos. Pongo un ejemplo del array de origen:

```php
    'origin' => [
            'dice_type' => '1d8',
            'result' => [
                1 => [
                    'description' => 'Accidental. The trading post came about due to an accident, such as a caravan breaking down or mistaken directions. What was set up to deal with the accident eventually became the trading post.',
                    'special' => null,
                    'sub_table' => null,
                    'table_modifications' => null,
                ],
                2 => [
                    'description' => 'Business Venture. The trading post was established by a wealthy entrepreneur specifically to be a trading post from the start.',
                    'special' => null,
                    'sub_table' => null,
                    'table_modifications' => null,
                ],
                // ...
                8 => [
                    'description' => 'Wilderness Expert. The trading post was started when a trapper, hunter or guide set up a camp, in order to aid those passing through the area.',
                    'special' => null,
                    'sub_table' => null,
                    'table_modifications' => null,
                ],
            ],
        ],
```

Cuando el usuario esté creando el puesto comercial y presione el botón generar, obtendrá un resultado del 1 al 8 y en la tabla trading_posts, la columna origin guardará ese resultado. Así a la hora de recuperar este puesto comercial sabrá que tiene ir a este mismo array y obtener los datos que hay en la key.

El dilema viene en que no se si esto es muy correcto hacerlo en los archivos de traducción, ya que como digo son reglas de negocio, pero claro, teniendo un array en cada idioma puedo internacionalizar la aplicación de una forma mucho más sencilla.

Añadir que no quiero usar campos json en la tabla ni usar el spatie-translatable.

La aproximación que estoy haciendo es correcta o debería hacerlo de otra forma? ¿Qué opináis?
Gracias de antemano.

### edit

Para explicarme mejor. Tengamos en consideración la siguiente clase:

```php
    class TradingPostData
    {
        protected string $diceType;
        protected array $results;
        protected ?array $subTables;
    
        protected function __construct(array $data)
        {
            $this->diceType = $data['dice_type'];
            $this->results = $data['results'];
            $this->subTables = $data['sub_tables'];
        }
    
        public static function fromArray(array $array): TradingPostData
        {
            return new self($array);
        }
    
        // ...
    }
```

Mi duda es, sería correcto hacer?

```
$originTradingPostData = TradingPostData::fromArray(__('settlements.trading_post.origin))
```

Es correcto que el array que le pase a este modelo de datos sea el array del archivo de traducción?

Comment: La respuesta corta, en no. Los archivos de traducciones son para traducir palabras o frases a varios idiomas. Es lo podrias poner en un archivo config, o en los modelos mismo, o cerca de las migraciones/seeders... depende, parece algo que insertas una vez en la BD y usas un modelo Asentamiento, o Configuracion para obtener sus datos cada vez en vez de leerla del archivo

Comment: Si pones el archivo en el directorio `/config/myapp.php`, luego puedes facilmente acceder al valor del array con `$value = config('myapp.origin.result');` creo que es lo mas parecido a lo que estas haciendo, y es justamente para configuracion

Comment: Entonces tendría que tener dos arrays por cada idioma, uno para la traducción y otro para la config? o lo he entendido mal?

Comment: Tendrias que tener un array por cada idioma para traduccion, y un array de configuracion. Son dos cosas distintas, la estructura que muestras no tendria sentido para un [array de traduccion](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/localization#defining-translation-strings). Tal vez puedas usar una traduccion en el archivo de configuracion `__('messages.result.description')` o `__('Business Venture. The...')`, habria que probarlo

Comment: Hola @porloscerrosΨ gracias por contestar. Los archivos de traducción si que permiten arrays asociativos. Si tu por ejemplo le pasas __(orign.results) lo que te devuelve es el array results que está dentro del array origin completamente traducido.

Comment: Si, a lo que me referia es a un array con clve numerica o con valores en null, en las traducciones pones lo que queres traducir, y en el valor traducido